# Thread 1's stack valgrind problem for a code in C

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable, valgrind

So I have a hashtable with a vector of linkedlists. In each list, every node has a pointer to the next node and a pointer to a 'struct aut' that contains an int and a pointer to a linkedlist where each node has a number stored inside.

Line 406 says:  my_id2 = * (int64_t *)curr->data;
Where curr is a node that stores an int inside the linkedlist inside the struct aut pointer inside a linkedlist inside a hashtable

```
==16921== Invalid read of size 4
==16921==    at 0x114B09: get_erdos_distance (publications.c:406)
==16921==    by 0x10982D: parse_commands (in /home/***/I-Sem 2/SD/SD-teme/Tema 3/skel/tema3)
==16921==    by 0x108CAB: main (in /home/***/I-Sem 2/SD/SD-teme/Tema 3/skel/tema3)
==16921==  Address 0xfee1b124 is on thread 1's stack
==16921==  76 bytes below stack pointer

==16921== Invalid read of size 4
==16921==    at 0x114B0C: get_erdos_distance (publications.c:406)
==16921==    by 0x10982D: parse_commands (in /home/***/I-Sem 2/SD/SD-teme/Tema 3/skel/tema3)
==16921==    by 0x108CAB: main (in /home/***/I-Sem 2/SD/SD-teme/Tema 3/skel/tema3)
==16921==  Address 0xfee1b120 is on thread 1's stack
==16921==  80 bytes below stack pointer
```

Comment: I verified each LinkedList that stores numbers and they seem to put my numbers ok inside. Each node stores an int64_t, not an int. I don't understand where does the problem come from

Comment: Where does the curr->data come from? How did you allocate it?

Comment: I can only speculate as to what is happening without seeing your code. My guess is that you are not allocating the data storage on the heap and instead are using pointers to data that has a temporary lifespan on the stack.

Comment: void* new_key = malloc(sizeof(int64_t));
*(int64_t*)new_key = id_aux;

Comment: where id_aux is the parameter of the function; the int64_t that i want to add in the list

Comment: Should that be *new_key = id_aux;

Comment: and new_key is my curr->data

Comment: i tried *new_key but it gave me an error

Comment: new_key is a pointer. An assignment to it overwrites the pointer and not what it points to.

Comment: Best to post the code. It's virtually impossible to give meaningful help otherwise.